# Python appending two returns to two different lists

Tags: python, return, append

I am wanting to append two returned lists to two different lists such as

```
def func():
    return [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]

list1.append(), list2.append() = func()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the append the list `[1, 2, 3]` itself or its items?

Comment: Don't put the answer in your question.  Instead, accept one by clicking the tick.

Comment: I am thinking I am okay with appending because I will be outputting these to a xml file and I have my function running in a loop and I want the return to be on a separate line each time and each value in each list to be in separate columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to capture the return values first, **then** append:

```
res1, res2 = func()
list1.append(res1)
list2.append(res2)
```

You appear to be returning lists here, are you certain you don't mean to use `list.extend()` instead?

If you were extending `list1` and `list2`, you could use slice assignments:

```
list1[len(list1):], list2[len(list2):] = func()
```

but this is a) surprising to newcomers and b) rather unreadable in my opinion. I'd still use the separate assignment, then extend calls:

```
res1, res2 = func()
list1.extend(res1)
list2.extend(res2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just storing the return values?

```
a, b = func() #Here we store it in a and b
list1.append(a) #append the first result to a
list2.append(b) #append the second one to b
```

With this, if `a` was previously `[10]` and `b` was previously `[20]`, you'll have this result:

```
>>> a, b
[10, [1,2,3]], [20,[4,5,6]]
```

Nah, that wasn't difficult, was it?

By the way, you *probably* want to merge the lists. For this, you can use `extend`:

```
list1.extend(a)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A one line solution isn't possible (unless you use some cryptic hack, which is always a bad idea).

The best you can get is:

```
>>> list1 = []
>>> list2 = []
>>> def func():
...     return [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
...
>>> a,b = func()     # Get the return values
>>> list1.append(a)  # Append the first
>>> list2.append(b)  # Append the second
>>> list1
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> list2
[[4, 5, 6]]
>>>
```

It's readable and efficient.